# Boundedness of the subset $\{(z,w)\in \mathbb{C}^2:z^2 +w^2 =1\} \subset \mathbb{C}^2$

Tags: analysis, complex-numbers

> Is the set $$\{(z,w)\in \mathbb{C}^2:z^2 +w^2 =1\}$$ bounded in $\mathbb{C}^2$?

I know that for any $z$ in $\mathbb{C}^2$ we can find a $w$ which satisfies the given condition in the set . But from here I can not understand whether the given set is bounded or not. It is also unclear to me about the meaning of boundednesss in $\mathbb{C}^2$. Can anyone please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint** For any $\alpha \in \Bbb C$,
$$(\cos \alpha, \sin \alpha) \in \{(z, w) : z^2 + w^2 = 1 \} .$$

Boundedness in $\Bbb C^m$ is just the property inherited from the usual notion of boundedness under the identification $\Bbb C^m \leftrightarrow \Bbb R^{2m}$. Put another way, a subset $U \subset \Bbb C^m$ is bounded iff $\sup \{|\zeta| : \zeta \in U\} < \infty$.

Comment: +1, this is a good hint, but I think it is very common for people who never though about it that $\cos$ and $\sin$ are bounded, even though this is a contradiction with Liouville theorem.

Comment: Then for such people this hint provides two lessons, no? In any case, thank you.

Comment: Right, indeed !

Comment: Hence it is unbounded, right?

Answer (score 0):

For any $x\in \mathbb{R}$, take $$z=\sqrt{x(x-2i)},\;\;\;\;\; w=1+ix.$$

Comment: from here how can you say that the set is unbounded?

Comment: because $(z, w)$ belongs to the set and $|w|$ can be as large as you like

Answer (score 0):

The functions $\cosh t = \frac12 (e^t+e^{-t})$ and $\sinh t = \frac12 (e^t-e^{-t})$ satisfy $(\cosh t)^2 - (\sinh t)^2 = 1$ and both unbounded as $t\to\pm\infty$. Taking $z=\cosh t$ and $w=i\sinh t$ thus shows that the set is not bounded. This is basically the same example as Travis gave, but might be easier to grasp.

Another example is $z=it$ and $w=\sqrt{1+t^2}$. This is actually related to the last example, but might be even easier to grasp.